# Show or hide element on hover in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular material card with an "x" button.

just wanted the "x" button to be hidden normally and be shown while hovering on the card.

code for the card:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>hello title</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>hello content</mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

thought of using `ngClass` but didn't know how to tell it if user isHovering or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
<mat-card (mouseover)="showButton = true" (mouseleave)="showButton = false" >
    <mat-card-title>hello title</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>hello content</mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf = "showButton"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Declare the `showButton` variable in your component `.ts` file like this:

```
showButton: boolean = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is many way of soluation

**1**.you can set using `scss` or `css`

**html file**

```
<mat-card class="CARD">
   <mat-card-title>hello title</mat-card-title>
   <mat-card-content>hello content</mat-card-content>
   <mat-card-actions>
    <button class="CLOSE" mat-icon-button><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
   </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

**.scss file**

```
    .CLOSE {
        display : none;
      }
    .CARD {
           &:hover {
               .CLOSE {
                display : block !important
              }
            }
         }
```

**2**. Using `variables`
**.ts file**

```
 btnVisible: boolean = true;
```

**.html file**

```
<mat-card (mouseover)="btnVisible = false" (mouseleave)="btnVisible = true" >
<mat-card-title>hello title</mat-card-title>
<mat-card-content>hello content</mat-card-content>
<mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-icon-button *ngIf ="btnVisible"><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
</mat-card-actions>
```

Hope it will usefull for all !

Comment: The scss solution is more elegant and cleaner, in my thoughts. Thanks